# Invoking cmd command in c# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#

I was trying to invoke cmd command in c# and I have found this code:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "msg %username% Hello World";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

This should popup a dialog box in the screen, with text "Hello World". (Code hides the cmd window). But, nothing happens. I also used debugging methods, to be 100% sure that program reaches this code. It does, but it does not display the popup message. Any ideas where I may be mistaking?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the `Arguments` to this:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/C msg %username% Hello World";
```

`cmd.exe` needs the `/C` option. This tells `cmd.exe` to execute the following command and terminate again.

---

You can use `cmd /?` in a console window to show all options and parameters of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. With my previous code, I saw a lot of instances of cmd.exe in task manager (probably because it did not shut down). With this code, it shuts down and does not stay in task manager, but command still does not execute, I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: @MarijaNikola strange...I tested your code (with my change) and it worked...maybe it's because of `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` (I tested in a console app, so I already had a window)

Comment: @MarijaNikola tested again in a winforms app, it works for me (except that `%username%` seems empty...).